# Как грамотно обрабатывать ошибки в конструкторах? PHP

Tags: php, ооп, исключения

Допустим есть класс, который в конструкторе принимает массив и что-то делает с его элементами. Предположим, что элементы должны соответствовать какому-либо условию. Как правильно обработать случай, когда элемент не соответствует? Пользователь же должен как-то узнать об ошибке?

До этого изучал С++ и оттуда знаю, что бросать исключения в конструкторе - очень плохая идея. Относится ли это к PHP, а если да, то как уведомлять пользователей об ошибках в конструкторе?

Comment: Класс - это класс, а пользователь - это пользователь. Надо определиться, про что мы говорим. Класс чем занимается? Какого рода ошибки? Пользователь имеет к ним отношение, или нет?

Comment: Да, а что делает С++ если в конструкторе выясняется, что пришли невалидные данные?

Comment: @Ипатьев Я имел ввиду не фатальную ошибку. То есть объект может быть создан, но нужно уведомить пользователя, что класс будет не совсем такой, какой должен был быть. Например на вход подается массив чисел, а конструктор из всех четных чисел массива создает свой. Пользователь подал массив с разными числами и думает, что в классе будут все они, но в классе будут-то только с четными числами (как пример)

Comment: Почему нельзя вынести это в отдельную функцию и обозначить что она будет делать и возвращать? Конструктор подразумевается для создания объекта и инициализации его значений. Как вам уже написали выше - сделайте разделение.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov он и инициализирует, в том-то и проблема

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov однако из ответа ниже, видимо это единственное решение. Спасибо за подсказку вам и Ипатьеву

Comment: Ваша проблема в том, что вы путаете бизнес-логику и ошибки. В вашем сценарии, когда "шёл в комнату, попал в другую", никакой ошибки нет, и соотвстственно, негде кидать исключения. Если на основе введённых пользователем данных объект создаётся, то задача проинформировать пользователя о том, что создали не то что он хотел - это задача вашей безнес-логики, а не исключений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Аналогичный пример вашей проблемы

Предположим что у нас есть класс `DataBaseConnection` и для его работы нам необходим класс `DataBaseConfiguration`.

`DataBaseConfiguration` - используем для хранения настроек:

```php
class DataBaseConfiguration{
    private $url;
    
    private $userName;
    
    private $password;
    //Другие поля и Setterы и Getterы
}
```

`DataBaseConnection` - компонент системы, который инициализирует соединение с базой данных

```php
class DataBaseConnection
{

    /**
     * Создание компонента для работы с БД
     *
     * @param DataBaseConfiguration $configuration
     *
     * @throws Exception\DataBaseConnectionException
     */
    public function __construct(DataBaseConfiguration $configuration)
    {
        $this->initializeConnection($configuration);
    }

    /**
     * @param DataBaseConfiguration $configuration
     *
     * @throws Exception\DataBaseConnectionException
     */
    private function initializeConnection(DataBaseConfiguration $configuration)
    {
        try {
            //Как-то создаем подключение
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new Exception\DataBaseConnectionException("Can't initialize connection {$e->getMessage()}");
        }
    }
}
```

Как вы можете предположить, соединение с БД операция, которая не всегда выполнима, что означает в случае возникновения такой проблемы у вас получится не рабочий компонент системы.

Добавления Exception в конструктор класса, вы выдаете контракт использования пользователю данного компонента, на то что класс:

- Либо создается и работает корректно
- Либо не создается вообще и бросается `Exception`

### Ваша проблема

Так и с вашим классом, нет смысла в компоненте, который не работает :)

Создавая Exception:

- Вы спасаете себя от дальнейших проблем
- Создаете контракт использования
- Даете пользователю компонента контроль над происходящим.

### Дополнения

- Используйте PHPDoc's с аннотацией `@throws`
- Возможно вашему "массиву" необходима структура данных, но не факт  :)

Comment: Массив - это был пример. Однако спасибо за развернутый ответ. Проблему он не решил, но я понял, что в PHP лучше либо создавать целый объект, либо не создавать его вообще. Видимо, придется выносить эту логику в отдельный метод, как и советовал @Daniel Protopopov выше

Comment: К сожалению писал ответ до комментов ;/

Comment: Ничего, так или иначе ваш ответ прояснил мою ситуацию, так что спасибо

Comment: Если говорить о примере - массива, то у вас получается компонент, который хранит только четные числа аля `EvenNumberStorage` 

(Но опять же, немного странный пример) 

Скорее да нужен метод, который модифицирует массив оставляя в нем только четные числа

Comment: Какой-то странный ответ на вопрос "как обрабатывать ошибки у конструкторах", который заключается в "поймать и бросить заново"

Comment: @Ипатьев Вопрос был в том "А что делать, если что-то пошло не так". Читайте внимательно